# Make strand of text appear and another disappear on same delay

Tags: html, css, delay

How do I make a strand of text appear in 5 seconds, and another strand of text disappear in 5 seconds? I can do either one alone but together neither one will work. I've posted the code below. I tried to rename some of the functions for one of them and keep the other the same but that didn't work so I undid that.

```
<script>
// First strand of text

window.onload = function(){
  var theDelay = 5;
  var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)
}
function showText(){
  document.getElementById("delayedText").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="delayedText" style="visibility:hidden">
This text will appear after 5 seconds
</div>

<script>
// Second strand of text

window.onload = function(){
  var theDelay = 5;
  var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)
}
function showText(){
  document.getElementById("delayedText").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="delayedText" style="visibility:visible">
This text will disappear after 5 seconds
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. You're calling `window.onload` twice, which is unnecessary. You should bundle all functions and call them within `window.onload`.

Secondly, the two elements to be hidden and shown each have the ID of "delayedText", which means that the two different functions (one to hide, and one to display) are acting on the same objects at the same time, and canceling each other out.

Object IDs are meant to be unique. Create two objects with unique IDs, and call them each within the same function.

```
// Set the timer
var theDelay = 5;
function timer() {
    setTimeout( function(){
        toggleText();    
    }, theDelay * 1000 );
}
// Call the timer
timer();

// Toggle visibility
function toggleText() {
    document.getElementById("toShow").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("toHide").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URfk5/1/